# Overfitting reason in 2-stage model

Tags: overfitting

I'm trying to build an entity matching model. There are 2 kinds of features - binary (0/1) and text features. Initially I made a deep learning model that uses character level embeddings of some of the text features, word level embeddings of the other text features and also uses the binary features as inputs.

The output is through a softmax for 3 classes, so basically a $n\times 3$ array (where $n$ is the input data length).

I've done three splits - `train`, `val` and `test`, and for training the DL model through Keras, I've specified `train` as the training split and `val` as the validation split. I measured the performance on the `test` split to get DL model metrics. The softmax outputs for all three splits were obtained using `model_DL.predict`.

Next, I used a Random Forest model as a second stage. Inputs: all the binary features PLUS the softmax outputs as inputs. e.g. I took the `train` split, removed the text features and added in the columns of the predicted array as separate features. To be even more specific, if `predtrain` was obtained by using `model_DL.predict` on the `train` split, then the additional features were added using `train['class1prob'] = predtrain[:,0], train['class2prob'] = predtrain[:,1], train['class3prob'] = predtrain[:,2]`.

Similarly I did for `test` and `val` splits. Now I trained the RF on the augmented `train` split and measured its performance on the `val` and `test` splits. The F-score for the `train` and `val` splits was around 0.85, 0.74, 0.73 for the 3 classes respectively (i.e. performance was similar on both splits).

BUT for the `train` split the predictions were near perfect - 0.98, 0.99, 0.98 F-scores for the three classes. My intuition is that overfitting of the 2nd stage RF is understandable for `train`, since the softmax outputs were predicted using the 1st stage DL model, which in turn was already trained on `train`. Also, there's some data leakage for the `val` split since `val` was used as a validation set to finetune the DL model by Keras, so maybe even the val metrics aren't so reliable. But there is no leakage for the `test` set.

My question is, in this scenario have I made an error, or is this blatant overfitting normal for 2 stage models? If there's a glaring error, any way or best practice to fix that?